# How is LaTeX's online documentation produced?

Tags: documentation, latex2html, latex-project

I like the style of the LaTeX html online documentation on [latex-project.org](https://latex-project.org). I assume it is written in LaTeX and then somehow transformed into HTML.

I would like to produce a documentation in a similar manner for my own project. On [latex-project.org](https://latex-project.org) I could not find how they do this. I assume they use latex2html or htlatex and a custom template?

Could somebody please point me to a write-up of their tool chain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site is developed on github-pages so the bulk of the text is written in markdown, you can see the sources at

https://github.com/latex3/latex3.github.io

Actually the final version is not hosted on github pages but that's a technical issue which doesn't affect the authoring.

The HTML generation, as usual on github pages is done using Jekyll, in this case using a customisation provided by Jonas, see https://www.latex-project.org/about/team/